# how to show downloaded content on webview in metroUI

Tags: c#, webview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to show some downloaded content (like images, videos, css etc.) on my webview. However I can only show files on my project or content from www. I've tried ms-appdata scheme but it still shows nothing.

ps: downloaded content is on my applicationdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use WebView to display downloaded items.
Second, for referencing files in Application Data folder you need to use **proper Uri scheme**, in this case:

```
ms-appdata:///local/
```

There is a nice article describing available Uri schemes to use in your Windows 8 app:
[URI schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx)